# NHibernate HybridSessionBuilder, how to switch hibernate cfg based upon url values

Tags: nhibernate

I am using the HybridSessionBuilder supplied by Palermo and his team .. [link](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/use-this-nhibernate-wrapper-to-keep-your-repository-classes-simple/) ..

We have our staging environments set up so that the url will be one of the following based on the environment

- web-test.company.com
- web-cert.company.com
- web.company.com

what we normally do is take a look at the url and if it has "-test" we use the test configurations and so on (connection strings, etc).

This is the first project that uses nhibernate in this type of environment. What would be a good way to tell the Session Builder to use the correct hibernate cfg (I will build 1 for each environment).

The HybridSessionBuilder lives in an infrastructure layer and is injected into repositories via StructureMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I select a single configuration file using the HybridSessionBuilder:

```
public Configuration GetConfiguration()
{
   var configuration = new Configuration();
   string cfgFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()).CodeBase) +
            "\\com.Data.nHibernate.cfg.xml";
   configuration.Configure(cfgFile);
   configuration.AddAssembly("com.Data");
   return configuration;
}
```

If you want to select configuration files based on the URL I would just identify the call stack that leads to this function and pass in either an enum value or the config file's name directly.